# How to get solid shadows cast from obstacles?

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting, shadows

I need clear shadows from the blinds on my character. There are some shadows, but they are very scattered, which, of course, do not seem to exist.

[image]

[image]

What I've already tried:
1 - Move the blinds point-blank to the character so that the light does not have time to scatter along the way

2 - dripped in the light source settings

3 - Set up different types of light (Sun, point, area, etc.)

4 - Work with the blinds material and drip into its settings

5 - Climbed in render settings

6 - Climbed in object settings

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't talk about your light settings, it should work if you decrease the light Radius value (or Angle value for the sun), if it still doesn't work maybe share your file? (put a simple cube instead of your character) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I already figured out the problem, thanks) decrease the light Radius value -  it helped me)

Answer (score 2):

this parameter should have been set to 0

[image]